# Combine 2 or more XML files

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to combine the contents of 2 or more xml files in PHP.

What is the best and most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is this just a concatenation, or more of a blending / joining?

Comment: simple concatenation and to be returned as an xml object to work with as opposed to adding to a seperate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with 'simplexml' so I assume you are looking for a solution using that. Will http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php#92272 help you?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php#91561 is another method.